# Grouping by entries in a column in Pandas Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a Pandas DataFrame with `id` as `index`, `brand`, `type` and `price` as columns that looks like the following:

```
                   brand  type  price
id                                                                 
1234567            A      X         39.0
2391923            A      Y         20.0
1595354            B      X         12.4
6699874            B      Z         88.2
0998877            B      Z         100.1
8791392            C      X         32.0
```

I would like to "group" by brand and category to find the average prices organized like such:

```
             X      Y      Z
brand_A  $$.$$  $$.$$  $$.$$
brand_B  $$.$$  $$.$$  $$.$$
brand_C  $$.$$  $$.$$  $$.$$
```

I know that using `group_by` with the `.mean()` method gets me close to what I want but not exactly. Any tips are appreciated.

Comment: where is category?

Comment: It's hard to say since you've not provided the values for output. Do you mean `df.pivot_table(index='brand', columns='type', values='price', aggfunc='mean')`? (`aggfunc='mean'` is the default but I'm just being explicit here for clarity)

Comment: kindly provide the expected output

Comment: The expected output would be the average of the prices. I have not provided the exact values that I wish to get as I have not provided the full table that I am working with.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

i think you can use `.groupby` and `.unstack`

```
df1 = df.groupby(['brand','type'])['price'].mean().unstack(1,fill_value=0)

print(df1)

type      X     Y      Z
brand
A      39.0  20.0   0.00
B      12.4   0.0  94.15
C      32.0   0.0   0.00
```

Comment: `.unstack(1, fill_value=0)` would prevent a copy and also prevent dtype conversion (if these were not already floats NaN would change the dtype)

Comment: @HenryEcker I always forget about the additional arguments in `.unstack` thanks for the tip and the information about when the copy gets created. Cheers!